# Mouse Event for NSRect

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have an NSEvent and want to detect when a rect is clicked so this is the code I have:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event;
{
    NSPoint clickedPoint = [event locationInWindow];
    //perform code for clickedPoint    
}
```

Instead of using locationInWindow how can I convert a rect or view to a NSPoint so that it will check if I clicked the rect? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, consider whether you really want to override `mouseDown:` or whether overriding `mouseUp:` might be a better option. If this click is similar to something like clicking a button, it’s generally a better idea to override `mouseUp:` rather than `mouseDown:`, as `mouseUp:` would allow the user to “change their mind” by dragging the mouse out of the button’s rect before letting go of the mouse.

`NSEvent`’s `locationInWindow` gives the location of the event in the base window’s coordinates. To convert that location to the view’s local coordinate system, you can use `NSView`'s [convertPoint:fromView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/convertPoint%3afromView%3a) like in the following:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
  NSPoint eventLocation = [event locationInWindow];
  NSPoint location = [self convertPoint:eventLocation fromView:nil];
  // handle the logic of what to do given the point
}
```

See [Cocoa Event-Handling Guide: Getting the Location of an Event](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventHandlingBasics/EventHandlingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH5-SW15) for more information.